# Unicode variant selector (u+FE00) not working with Noto Sans Myanmar (Burmese)

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode, variant

I'm having trouble getting the Unicode variant selector character working.

The Unicode range for Burmese also covers a number of Tai languages like Shan and Aiton. In Aiton, there is a very slight change to the letter forms, handled by the u+FE00 character. U+1000 (က) is the consonant /k/, and U+1000 U+FE00 (က︀) is the variant form, with a tiny dot added on the bottom left.

I have text, in TexPad on macOS, which in the editor view shows the dots (i.e. the variant selector character is working), but then when I compile (XeLaTeX), it shows up without the dot.

I'm using Noto Sans Myanmar, which does normally show the dots.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\myanmar{Noto Sans Myanmar}
% \newfontfamily\myanmar{Noto Sans Myanmar}[Variant=1] makes no difference

\begin{document}

% \addfontfeature{Variant=01} also has no effect

% with dots
{\myanmar က︀ိင︀်ꩫ︀ႃလ︀ႃ}

% no dots
{\myanmar ကိင်ꩫႃလႃ}

\end{document}
```

Here's a screenshot of the editor view, showing the difference in case it doesn't show up on SE.

[image]

This is the output of the MWE, which does not use the variants as needed:

[image]

Converting to codepoints explicitly, e.g.  `\symbol{"1000}\symbol{"fe00}\symbol{"102d}...` breaks it further and none of the diacritics show up properly. Same with `\char"1000` etc.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: I found https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-fonts/issues/2066

Comment: `Variant=01` is unavailable for the default language, but Aiton is not among the languages `fontspec` recognizes at this time (see p. 35 of the `fontspec` manual). No idea whether or how this is related to the issue reported at github.

Comment: Thanks. So if I'm understanding both of these correctly, the issue is that fontspec doesn't recognise Phake/Aiton and so doesn't make the conversions, even though it should be something the font normally handles.

That gives me a direction to go, at least. I'll see if I can try without fontspec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Amended answer*

With feedback from the comments, the `Script=` option is enough to activate the variation selectors (which is a glyph, VS1, sitting at U+FE00); and language setting has no effect (in this case).

[image: with dots]

Plus, `fontspec` also allows renaming of script tags (and other things): `\newfontscript{Phake}{mym2}`.

So you can write things like

```
\newfontfamily\myanmara{Noto Serif Myanmar}[Colour=blue,Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Phake]
```

A recent Lualatex install does not need the `Renderer=HarfBuzz` part.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xparse}% not neeeded for up-to-date distr
\ExplSyntaxOn
    % a handy command
    \cs_set_eq:NN \fontfeature \fontspec_if_feature:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand\showyes{{\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}Yes}}
\newcommand\showno{{\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}No}}

\newfontscript{Phake}{mym2}
\newfontlanguage{Karen}{KSW}
\newfontlanguage{Mon}{MON}
\newfontfamily\myanmara{Noto Serif Myanmar}[Colour=blue,Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Phake]
\newfontfamily\myanmarb{Noto Serif Myanmar}[Colour=red,Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Phake,Language=Karen]
\newfontfamily\myanmarc{Noto Serif Myanmar}[Colour=brown,Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Phake,Language=Mon]

\begin{document}

Has \verb|ss01|: {\myanmara \fontfeature{ss01}{\showyes}{\showno}}

%with dots (with variation selectors) (using Phake=mym2 script)

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\rowcolor{blue!15}
Language & Result \\
\hline
None & \myanmara က︀ိင︀်ꩫ︀ႃလ︀ႃ \\
Karen & \myanmarb က︀ိင︀်ꩫ︀ႃလ︀ႃ \\
Mon & \myanmarc က︀ိင︀်ꩫ︀ႃလ︀ႃ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

%\bigskip
%with no dots
%
%{\myanmarb ကိင်ꩫႃလႃ}

\end{document}
```

---

**Xelatex**

[image: xelatx]

A couple of hundred glyphs are up in the Private Use Area and all of them have Unicode value = -1 ("bad character"), so accessing them the traditional way (with `\UcharNNNN`, where `NNNN` is the Unicode codepoint) doesn't work: neither lualatex nor xelatex can reach them that way.

In Xelatex, there are XeTeX primitives which allow glyph access by their position number in the font.

<strike>A TecKit mapping file, or</strike>   expl3's regex/find-replace ability, will allow a convenient transliteration ASCII input method to work. TecKit mapping uses Unicode codepoints.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand\tl[1]{{\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{m}{n}\small#1}}
\font\myanmara="[NotoSerifMyanmar-Regular.ttf]'' at 12pt


\begin{document}

\myanmara 
က︀ိင︀်ꩫ︀ႃလ︀ႃ 

\tl{glyph count = }
\count255=\XeTeXcountglyphs\myanmara\relax
\tl{\the\count255}

\myanmara\XeTeXglyph130\XeTeXglyph384\XeTeXglyph134\XeTeXglyph406\XeTeXglyph146\XeTeXglyph373\XeTeXglyph150\XeTeXglyph373


\begin{multicols}{5}
\count255=1
\loop
\ifnum\count255 < \XeTeXcountglyphs\myanmara
\noindent
\centering
{\tl{\the\count255=}}
{\color{blue}\large\myanmara\XeTeXglyph\count255}
\par\noindent\centering
\tl{\tiny[\XeTeXglyphname\myanmara\count255]}\par
\ \par\hrule\par\ \par
\advance\count255 by 1
\repeat
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

---

**Lualatex**

For reference, glyphs can be accessed by index/key in Lualatex too, using lua code.

*Direct* access to alternate glyphs, instead of indirectly via font features, variation selectors, etc, can be done using luatex's font cache information and *not* using HarfBuzz as font renderer. (HarfBuzz renders all glyphs the "normal" way, via ligature tables, substitution tables, etc. - all this information is in the font cache file, too.)

Luatex knows about fonts via its font cache, a set of files containing font information in lua-table structure.

In this case, we can load the `.../texlive/2020/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/notoserifmyanmar-regular.lua` file with the `require` command and iterate through, say, the `descriptions` table and its subtables, to get at this type of entry:

```
 ["descriptions"]={
...

  [983058]={
   ["boundingbox"]=13,
   ["index"]=130,
   ["name"]="ka_khm",
   ["unicode"]=4096,
   ["width"]=1037,
  },
...
}
```

where `[983058]` is the "internal key", the slot number or Unicode codepoint of the glyph in the font, `["index"]` is the glyph ID (GID), `["name"]` is obvious, and `["unicode"]` is the Unicode codepoint that this glyph relates to (glyph "ka" at `4096`). Glyph "ka_khm"'s unicode will be mapped to `-1` by the time HarfBuzz sees it with OpenType eyes, so not directly accessible that way.

(The glyph is indirectly accessible via, say, its ligature bindings:

```
    ["features"]=316,
    ["flags"]=117,
    ["index"]=13,
    ["name"]="s_s_14",
    ["nofsteps"]=1,
    ["order"]=139,
    ["steps"]={
     {
      ["coverage"]={
       [4096]={
        [65024]={
         ["ligature"]=983058,
        },
```

so no problems there.)

The trick for *direct* access to these substitutes and alternates is *not* to use HarfBuzz as the font-renderer.

[image: all glyphs]

Some glyphs will be positioned awkwardly with this method since it places them standalone and therefore out of context.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xparse}

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.3cm} \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

\newfontfamily\flab{Noto Serif}% for labels
\newfontfamily\fmyan{NotoSerifMyanmar-Regular.ttf}

\let\nc\newcommand

%--------------------------------------
\begin{luacode}
    function openmyfontfile(xxx)
        local fft = require(xxx)
  
        tex.sprint("\\begin{multicols}{2}")

            for k, v in pairs(fft.descriptions) do
        
            for kk, vv in pairs(fft.descriptions[k]) do
        if kk == "name" then 
                    tex.sprint("\\noindent\\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|}")
                    tex.sprint("\\hline")
                    tex.sprint("{\\flab\\small " .. k .. "}&")
                    tex.sprint("{\\flab\\small \\detokenize{"  .. vv .. "}}&")
                    tex.sprint("\\cellcolor{blue!12}\\Uchar" .. k .."\\\\")         
                    tex.sprint("\\hline")
                    tex.sprint("\\end{tabular}\\par")
            end
            end
            end
        
            tex.sprint("\\end{multicols}")

 end
\end{luacode}
\nc\doopenff[1]{%
{\directlua{openmyfontfile("#1")}}
}

%===============

\begin{document}
\fmyan
\doopenff{<..long path name..>/texlive/2020/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/notoserifmyanmar-regular.lua}

\end{document}
```

---

*Original answer*

[image: with dots]

From a hint on the github link, the dots are stored under `StylisticSet=1` (`ss01`).

They are accessed via the script option (`Script=Myanmar`).

Lualatex has to be explicitly told to use the HarfBuzz font-renderer. In Xelatex, it should be the default.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\myanmar{Noto Serif Myanmar}[StylisticSet=1,Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Myanmar]
\newfontfamily\myanmarsans{Noto Sans Myanmar}[StylisticSet=1,Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Myanmar]

\begin{document}
Serif:

% with dots
{\myanmar က︀ိင︀်ꩫ︀ႃလ︀ႃ}

% no dots
{\myanmar ကိင်ꩫႃလႃ}

\bigskip
Sans Serif:

% with dots
{\myanmarsans က︀ိင︀်ꩫ︀ႃလ︀ႃ}

% no dots
{\myanmarsans ကိင်ꩫႃလႃ}

\end{document}
```

Comment: At least on my system, these fonts do not contain the `ss01` feature and therefore the `StylisticSet=1` option is not needed. Nevertheless the code works for me on LuaLaTeX since specifying the script enables the feature. BTW at least on an up-to-date system this should also work without `Renderer=HarfBuzz` since it's supported by the Node renderer.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thanks for the feedback! Have amended the answer. With hindsight, the `.ttf` in the filename should have been a clue. :)  `otfinfo -f ...` returns nothing, of course.

Comment: @Cicada Thank you. This works a treat with LuaLaTeX. I haven't managed to get it working with XeLaTeX for some reason, even with some adjustments, however I can just shift over to LuaLaTeX for my purposes so this is great. I've marked this as a correct answer, but if you have any thoughts on XeLaTeX not working I'd be interested to read them. Thanks again.

Comment: @YhilanKo Don't know how to get Xelatex and variation selectors to work (Manchu could be another example). Glyph-access is possible, though - see amended answer. There are 739 glyphs in the Noto Myanmar, multiple scripts, shn, phk, khm and so on, according to the glyph names. A transliteration input method, either from Latin or Myanmar (or anything else), could be set up (using expl3 regex, or teckit mapping).

Comment: Version 2.001 of Noto Serif Myanmar has 725 glyphs, so the positions have shifted slightly and the glyph sequence now is : `\XeTeXglyph131\XeTeXglyph382\XeTeXglyph135\XeTeXglyph400\XeTeXglyph147\XeTeXglyph372\XeTeXglyph151\XeTeXglyph372`.